# Where and how to find an internship in Ireland?

Tags: students, ireland

So, here's the situation. I'm a French student (studying web and computers) and I have an internship to do starting in February.

For personnal reasons I'd like to travel abroad in an English-speaking country using the internship I have to do. I'm particularly interested in going to Ireland because I already went there in vacation and found this country lovely.

So here's my question:

Are there any particular ways to find an internship in Ireland? Like a website, specific forums or websites or such ways? If not, what about jobs (because it's almost the same when you think about it)

Comment: AFAIK the job market situation is pretty dire in Ireland at the moment, young Irish people leave by the thousands… In any case, the kind of internship you are looking for is called “[industrial or work] placement” in Ireland, if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's like looking for a job basically. You would need to look at jobs and internships websites, go through the offers and apply individually. For example [jobs.ie](http://www.jobs.ie/work_experience_internship_jobs.aspx)

Once you've found a company that wants you, emigrating to Ireland is pretty simple. I'm French myself, I've worked in Ireland for 4 years, and the hardest part is to find the position. Although there are plenty of big companies like Google, Facebook, Microsoft, etc. They have their customer support platforms in Ireland.